# Jquery get next certain element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
    var one = $("td[data-unit='sword']:first");
    var two = /*same tr, different td */  $("input[value='Selecteren']:first").click();
```

I want to get var two within the same tr as var one by using var one (so I can't just find td X on row X and automatically get var two on the same tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DOM traversal function to search from the containing `tr`.

```
var two = one.closest("tr").find("input[value='Selecteren']:first").click();
```